# How to call XSLT from XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for a possibility of calling a second XSLT from first XSLT.

My XML input looks like

```
<xml>
  <Subject name ="A1" type="a">
  <Subject name ="B2" type="b">
  <Subject name ="C1" type="c">
  <Subject name ="A2" type="a">
  <Subject name ="B1" type="b">
  <Subject name ="C2" type="c">
  <Subject name ="A3" type="a">
</xml>
```

What I want to do is something like

```
<xsl>
 if type = "a" call "XSL_A" with above XML-Input
 if type = "b" call "XSL_B" with above XML-Input
 if type = "c" call "XSL_C" with above XML-Input

 Do-Something with above XML-Input
<xsl>
```

Every "sub-xslt" shall take the complete input and do something with it, including creating a special named file.

As searching the web for a solution or a hint hasn't been successful.
Is this possible to do?
Or even sensible?

Answer (score 6):

> Or even sensible?

No, it is not sensible to think of calling XSLT procedurally, but that you're asking the question is a good sign that you're recognizing that there's probably a better way...

### Pattern matching

Do not think *procedurally* in terms of "calling" other XSLT.  Think instead *declaratively* in terms of ***pattern matching*** the input.

For

```
<Subject name ="A1" type="a"/>
```

instead thinking

- `if type = "a" call "XSL_A" with above XML-Input`

think

- When matching a `Subject` whose `@type` is `"a"`, output `something`

or, in XSLT,

```
<xsl:template match="Subject[@type='a']>
    <something id="{@name}"/>
</xsl>
```

so that

```
<Subject name ="A1" type="a"/>
```

is translated to

```
<something id="a"/>
```

in the output.

---

### XSLT file organization

Orthogonal to the above match-driven design approach, it is possible to organize and combine XSLT files.  Use `xs:include` to bring in another stylesheet as a separate part of the one you're writing; use `xs:import` to bring in another stylesheet like or based on the one you're writing such that you'd like to override templates.

For more details on `xs:include` vs `xs:import`, see:

- [Combining Stylesheets with Include and Import](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/01/xslt/)
- [Tip: Use imports and includes to override XSLT templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipimpinc/index.html) for a good overview of `xs:import` vs `xs:include`.
- [Combining Stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets) in the [**XSLT 1.0** Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt).
- For XSLT 2.0, for conditional inclusion, consider the [`xsl:use-when`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion) attribute, which can be added to `xs:import` (or `xs:include` or any other XSLT instruction).

### Modes

Finally, and orthogonal to both of the above dimensions, XSLT supports modes for controlling the applicability of a templates.  For more information on modes, see [Can one give me the example for “mode” of template in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4486869/290085)?

Comment: Nice post, i deleted mine in favour  of yours. I hope OP notices yours.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. In fact a combination of _result-document_ and _include(s)_ did the job to me.  As you say  "_Do not think procedurally in terms_" might be the (my) main problem with XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to call an XSLT stylesheet dynamically then you need XSLT 3.0 with the https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-transform function. On the other hand what you have posted with e.g. `if type = "a" call "XSL_A"` with above XML-Input simply looks like a possible search for template based matching and additionally modes with e.g. `<xsl:template match="Subject[@type = 'a']" mode="a">...</xsl:template>` where you could then write modules for each mode and include/import them in the main stylesheet.